# Does orchestra need "the" before it?

Tags: nouns, collective-nouns

Does the sentence

> *It requires full orchestra and progressively adds each of the four brass bands*

need *the* between "requires" and "full"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The use of the definite article "The"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217858/the-use-of-the-definite-article-the)

Comment: Also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198392/the-use-of-the-article-the-position

Answer (score 5):

No, it doesn't.

*Full orchestra* is a technical term of music, and is generally used without an article. It does not have quite the same meaning as the ordinary noun phrase *the/a full orchestra*: it refers to something like a property or quality of a piece of music, rather than an actual physical orchestra.

A couple of example from the Corpus of Global Web English:

> " 16 of her songs re-imagined and re-arranged with full orchestra."
>
> "the Suite in G major for full orchestra,"
>
> "explore the possibilities of instrumentation from solo piano to wind band and to full orchestra"

(Most of the examples of "full orchestra" in that Corpus do have an article).

In a case like this I would certainly not use "the", and I think most musicians wouldn't do so.

**Edit**: I've realised that this isn't a special property of the expression *full orchestra*, but of the way it's used by musicians. Many other expressions denoting musical forces behave the same way: *choir*, *choir and organ*, *string quartet*, *full organ*, *wind band*, *brass band*, *small orchestra*, *piano solo*, *two guitars*, *piano four hands*. All these can have works *written/arranged/published for* them or *performed by* them, never with an article.

Comment: Upvote. I didn't realize it was a musical term.